# Marketing cloud Query Single field split into multiple fields

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

I have a data extension that has duplicate email addresses with each duplicate having a different rank associated with it. I need to dedupe the email addresses but keep the different ranks in added fields.

So I currently have:

```
Email_address, Rank
Email1, rank1
Email1, rank2
Email1, rank3
Email2, rank1
Email2, rank2
```

And what I need is:

```
Email_address, Rank1, Rank2, Rank3
Email1, rank1, rank2, rank3
Email2, rank1, rank2
```

I've tried using the CASE function in an SOQL query but it's not returning the outcome I was looking for. Is there a way of getting the data how I need it using querys?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could achieve this with a self join. Something like...

```
SELECT Email_Address, 
t1.Rank as Rank1, 
t2.Rank as Rank2, 
t3.Rank as Rank3
FROM table t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t2 on t1.EmailAddress = t2.EmailAddress and t2.Rank = 'rank2'
LEFT OUTER JOIN table t3 on t1.EmailAddress = t3.EmailAddress and t3.Rank = 'rank3'
WHERE 1=1
AND t1.rank = 'rank1'
```

(I always throw 1=1 so each clause thereafter can start with AND)

Comment: The only issue you might run into with this (and it may not be a possibility in your use case) is if the email address does not have a 'rank1' value in Rank, it will not appear in your results.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to keep all the ranks in 1 single field? If yes, then you can use STUFF with FOR XML PATH functions in SQL. You can check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211506/how-stuff-and-for-xml-path-work-in-sql-server)